# React Native Grid Layout with section headers

Tags: ios, gridview, reactjs, react-native

I've implemented a card list similar to this: https://github.com/yelled3/react-native-grid-example, however, it seems as though using

```
list: {
  justifyContent: "center",
  flexDirection: "row",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
}
```

and

```
section: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: "row",
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  marginBottom: 10,
  justifyContent: "center",
}
```

in the styles doesn't allow section headers to render properly, and they dramatically change the layout of the listview.

The section headers are rendered as follows:

```
<View style={styles.section}>
  <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderText}>----{sectionId}----</Text>
</View>
```

I have gotten it working with section headers without the section wrap, but having one card per row is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Same here with RN 0.35, section header are rendered inline with the list elements, there is no separation into sections.
see attached image

The list code:

```
     <ListView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        margin: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 6,
      }}
      dataSource={this.state.symbolsDataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        overflow: 'hidden'
      }}
      enableEmptySections
      removeClippedSubviews
      showVerticalScrollIndicator
      keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps
      renderFooter={() => <View style={{ height: 240 }}/>}
      initialListSize={30}
      renderSectionHeader={(sectionData, sectionID) =>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center',fontSize: fixFont(20), color: Colors.darkBlue }}>{sectionID}</Text>
        </View>
      }
      scrollRenderAheadDistance={400/*pixels*/}
      pageSize={4/*how many items to render each loop*/}

    />
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS0yg.png)